# Can't set Build Action for Clean And Build in Netbeans

Tags: gradle, netbeans

Gradle project in Netbeans 14.  I was able to get build, clean, rebuild, and test to do what I want, but the other default action is "Clean And Build".  There is no equivilant to this under "Configure Action".  I tried hacking the config file and guessing and creating a custom cleanAndBuild, but none map to the "Clean And Build" menu option.  Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug I need to go try to fix?